# Splitting structure or duplicate calls or a better way in rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The following code is used as an example of my problem. A structure named `State` contains a number of `Resident`s.
Now there is a function that needs to modify both the State property and one of the Resident's properties.
Since it is not possible to get mutable borrows of State and one of the Residents in this State at the same time. The code can not compile.

I can think of two ways to solve it.
One is that just give only one parameter to modify_state_and_resident(): a mutable reference of State is provided. But I have to call the code to find Resident in hash map again in modify_state_and_resident(), which is expensive.

Another way is to split the State structure, splitting its properties and residents into separate variables. But this would bring other logical problems. After all, this is a complete entity that has to be referenced everywhere at the same time.

I don't know if there is a more perfect way to solve it.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Resident {
    age: i32,
    name: String,
    viewcnt: i32,
}

use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct State {
    version: i32,
    residents: HashMap<String, Resident>,
}

// This function cann not be invoked from modify_state_and_resident
fn show_resident(resident: &Resident) {
    println!("{:?}", resident);
}

fn modify_state_and_resident(class: &mut State, resident: &mut Resident) {
    // I do not want to call hash get again.
    class.version = class.version + 1;
    resident.viewcnt = resident.viewcnt + 1;
}

#[test]
fn whole_part_mutable() {
    let mut s = State {
        version: 1,
        residents: HashMap::from([
            (
                String::from("this is a man who named Aaron"), 
                Resident{age: 18, name: String::from("Aaron"), viewcnt: 0}
            ),
        ])};

    // get is expensive,  I just want to call it when neccessary
    let r = s.residents.get_mut("this is a man who named Aaron").unwrap();
    // can not call from other function 
    show_resident(r);

    modify_state_and_resident(&mut s, r);
}
```

Comment: Why not make a method on state that only takes `&mut self` and  `&mut Resident` and desctructure your `Resident` struct in there? Then it doesn't matter if you add fields to `Resident` it should be backwards compatible as long as `Resident` is not public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destructure the `State` struct `&mut` to get individual access to both parts:

```rust
fn modify_state_and_resident(version: &mut i32, resident: &mut Resident) {
    // I do not want to call hash get again.
    *version = *version + 1;
    resident.viewcnt = resident.viewcnt + 1;
}

#[test]
fn whole_part_mutable() {
    let mut s = State {
        version: 1,
        residents: HashMap::from([
            (
                String::from("this is a man who named Aaron"), 
                Resident{age: 18, name: String::from("Aaron"), viewcnt: 0}
            ),
        ])};

    let State { version, residents } = &mut s;
    // get is expensive,  I just want to call it when neccessary
    let r = residents.get_mut("this is a man who named Aaron").unwrap();
    // can not call from other function 
    show_resident(r);

    modify_state_and_resident(version, r);
    println!("{:?}", s);

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0258f3b09de083abdacd8b3bb2eece1f)

Comment: This is an acceptable solution. But I always feel that this way of binding function signatures to specific fields is not particularly scalable. For example, I now have many version fields that need to be modified, so they all have to be introduced in the function parameters.

Comment: @progquester, the other solution would be to use an Rc<RefCell> for the hashmap or something like that so you can freely get a share of the whole thing iirc.